# How do I make a slash in a webpage with HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to produce a parallelogram/slash look in my webpage as follows:

[image: rectangles]

It's easy to smash two divs together and then you have a rectangle next to a rectangle, but this slash is mind boggling. Is this possible with pure CSS or HTML? The examples I've seen all use SVGs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
html,
body {
    min-height: 100%; /* demo only */
}

#page {
    min-height: 100vh; /* demo only */
}

#page:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
    height: 150%;
    left: -10%;
    top: -25%;
    background: #F6990D;
    transform: rotate(4deg);
    border-right: 4px solid #FEBF78;
}
```

```html
<div id="page"></div>
```

Comment: Per your comment on mine, since yours is using a pseudo element just plop this on your pseudo class and it will smooth out those edges in your instance some amigo `backface-visibility: hidden;-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` 

Answer (score 3):

Just adding the linear option, but getting around the aliasing jagged edges will be tough regardless of the approach you take.

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;right: 0;bottom: 0; left:0;
  background: rgba(255,163,3,1);
  background: linear-gradient(95deg, rgba(255,163,3,1) 0%, 
                                     rgba(255,163,3,1) 9%, 
                                     rgba(245,205,135,1) 9%, 
                                     rgba(245,205,135,1) 10%, 
                                     rgba(255,255,255,1) 10%, 
                                     rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%
  );
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This is neat. Too bad about the jaggies. I wonder if there's a rendering property that could be employed to smooth it out.

Answer (score 3):

Start from a square div with four thick borders.

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-left: 50px solid green;
  border-top: 50px solid red;
  border-right: 50px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 50px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div> </div>
```

Now reduce the square to zero height.

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid green;
  border-top: 50px solid red;
  border-right: 50px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 50px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div> </div>
```

Now take off the left and bottom borders.

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid red;
  border-right: 50px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div> </div>
```

Finally, shrink the right border and make it transparent.

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid red;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div> </div>
```

You can adjust the numbers and add a shadow to make it look more like the example image. You can also add `transform: rotate(360deg)` to get cleaner aliasing *in certain scenarios* (this is a hack; it tricks the browser into switching to GPU-accelerated rendering mode if such a mode is available).

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 300px solid orange;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  filter: drop-shadow(10px 0 yellow);
  
  /* HACK: trick the browser into GPU-accelerated mode if possible,
   * this can help get cleaner aliasing in certain scenarios. */
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#slash {
      width: 15px;
      height: 100px;
      transform: skew(-20deg);
      background: red;
}
#container {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div id="slash">
 </div>
</div>
```

Just create a square and use skew transform